# Aurelia DI configuration class a la Spring @configuration

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, aurelia

I'm trying to figure out how to create a configuration class similar to what you would do with spring in Aurelia. The use case is to basically have consumed modules that provide functionality such as persistence to manage their own configuration (creating connections, registering dependencies, etc...).

In spring, you can have something like this (pseudocode, hasn't been tested):

```
@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean
    public Connection createConnection(string cnt) {
      // TODO: create connection
    }
}
```

The above code would execute the `createConnection` method and register a connection with the container, and also pass the `cnt` connection string variable when calling the method.

I believe I can do something like the following:

```
export class Dependencies {
    public configure(container: Container): void {
        let cnt: string = container.get('cnt');
        container.registerSingleton(Connection, () => {
           // TODO: create connection
        })
    }
}
```

And then call this somewhere else like so:

```
class App {
   constructor(dependencies: Dependencies) {
       dependencies.configure(this.container, this.cnt);
   }
}
```

The problem with this approach, is that configuration becomes explicit, and you have to know what the configuring class is named, what methods to call, as well as when to call it, since you want your connection string to be registered before creating a connection.

IMHO, having an explicit configuration step makes thing less tightly coupled. Also, having a way of providing dependencies by way of a factory method also makes configuration easier and more 'ergonomic'.

In summary, my two questions are:

1. Is it possible to have an explicit configuration `@configuration` step, like `@singleton` or `@transient`?
2. How do I register dependencies through a factory method/function, preferably using a decorator?

Answer (score 0):

This use case isn't supported by the aurelia-dependency-injection module, however there is now a module that adds support for it - [aurelia-factory-methods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-factory-methods).